How to return multiple items from a range to a single cell as a list but user chooses how many items in Google Sheets?
I have variable lists that will have 200–1000 values in them.
ex:
1   Reliable
2   Practical
3   Responsible
4   Organized
5   Detail-oriented
6   Logical
7   Hardworking
8   Dedicated
9   Honest
10  Loyal
    etc...

The user will be able to put a number in a cell and a different cell will spit out x number of these traits in a comma list.
I know how to do this in an if else chain with VLookup if I know how many things I need to return, but can't find any way to this using a loop instead so that the number of times it is repeated is limited. the VLookup also needs to generate a random number for the look up from the number of cells in the range.
So if the cell with number of values is B3 and it has a 3 in it. Then the cell displaying the traits which would have the looping vlookup may display "Loyal, Efficient, Patient"
Is there a way to accomplish this? It seems something that should be simple but I can't find anything online about doing something like this.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Consider showing a before and after to make this easier to follow.
